# How to expose my web application REST API using spring cloud data flow local

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Looking for help on my below query.

I have a web application with 2 REST API and i want to deploy this application to Spring Cloud Data Flow local server.  When other application in the local server calls this API, i want to execute my methods.
I tried below option and it didn't worked.
a) register my web application as app
b) created a task using the app in step(a)
c) created "HTTP|LOCAL-SERVER" stream and deployed
d) accessed REST URL using postman
e) my REST API call is not initiated as i cannot see any logs neither in the SCDF log nor application logs.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [http-client](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/httpclient/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-httpclient/README.adoc) processor?
That appears to solve your use case (if I understood your requirement correctly).

Comment: Hi Gopinathan,  Thank You for your reply.  If i use httpclient processor, what source & sink applications i should use?

Comment: Today i registered my REST application as type "APP" and i am able to call my REST API successfully whereas i am facing issue with PORT number.  Every time i start my spring cloud server (or) re-deploy spring assigning different port number.  Any way can i mention constant port number so that i share my rest API to third party?